# Parse string of special keys to get KeyCode

Tags: java, javafx, keycode

Am working on a JavaFX tool that requires the user to type in `String` representations of keyboard keys they want.

For this purpose I'm using the `KeyCode.getKeyCode(String)` function, where the documentation says

> Parses textual representation of a key."

That works perfectly for letters like `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"` and so on, but not on special keys like `"ESCAPE"`.

That one is obviously [on the list of constants for `KeyCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html). Is there another list of possible "textual representation" which are supposed to be used for receiving the key code?

Huge thanks!

Comment: You want to obtain a keycode from a string? Can't you use [`KeyCode.getKeyCode(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html#getKeyCode(java.lang.String))

Comment: @Vince Emigh Ehm, please read a little more than just the title. Exactly that function returns null for the String "ESCAPE".

Comment: Did you try [`getText()` or `getCharacter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html)?

Comment: @DragonGamer You can't wrap it to check for that corner case? No need for the attitude, this is *free*, and yeah I didn't fully read the post, big deal. Thanks for correcting me, but you lost help from me. No one will help when you react in such a way.

Comment: @Vince Emigh C'mon, I did not mean to attack you, but proposing exactly what I already tried?.. Well, I can code it manually of course through a switch statement or similar, but it does not work for any of the special keys apparently.

Comment: @Sedrick Jefferson Am not really seeing how those functions help since my start is a simple string like "ESCAPE". I do not have the keycode already.
What confuses me, is that the getKeyCode function does not seem to do what the documentation says.

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: @DragonGamer `KeyCode` is an enum. You could use  `KeyCode.valueOf(String)` or `Enum.valueOf(Class<T>, String)` as long as the argument matches an enum value char for char to get the enum value, such as `KeyCode.valueOf("ESCAPE")` for `KeyCode.ESCAPE`

Comment: @Vince Emigh Ahh well that worked perfectly! Strange that the getKeyCode function does not do the same already but that's alright. Thank you kindly! Feel free to post it as a normal answer so i can chose it as the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `KeyCode` is an `enum`, you could use [`KeyCode.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) to obtain the enum value from a string representation of the value, rather than relying on `KeyCode.getKeyCode(String)`.

For `KeyCode.ESCAPE`, simply use `KeyCode.valueOf("ESCAPE")`.

The `String` representation must match the `enum` value exactly. For `KeyCode.BACK_SLASH`, you must use `KeyCode.valueOf("BACK_SLASH")`.